get title from JSON
I am stuck!..
I have a jQuery script where i am populating a gallery of images from a JSON file, its like a lightbox type of thing.
But i want to have a title to my images, so i have created a second JSON file where i just keep, image name, and title.
I want to, in the loop, check the second JSON if the image name is there, and if it is, return the text that is the title...
This is the titles.json
[
    {"Img" : "fun1_001.jpg", "title" : "Title of image 001"},
    {"Img" : "fun1_002.jpg", "title" : "title of image 002"},
    {"Img" : "fun1_003.jpg", "title" : "title of image 002"}
]

What i want to do is to loop through all images, populate the gallery, and in the same time IF the image name is present in the titles.json, put that title in the loop.
This is the jQuery that populates the gallery. it calls a function named GetTitle(imagename,folder)
   //Load the gallery if you click the dropdown.
        $(document).on('click','#zmenu>div.item', function(){
            $('#dc_preload_image').empty();
            let zGallery=$(this).attr('data-value');
            $.getJSON('JSON/Gallerys/'+zGallery+'.json', { get_param: 'value' }, (data)=>{ 
                $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                console.log('anrop')
                    $('.galpop-info').galpop();
                    $("#dc_preload_image").preloader();    
                    $('#dc_preload_image').append('<li><a class="galpop-info" data-galpop-group="info"  title="'+GetTitle(element.imageName, zGallery)+'" href="BKND/Galleries/'+zGallery+'/pict/'+element.imageName+'"><img src="BKND/Galleries/'+zGallery+'/tmb/'+element.imageName+'" alt="'+element.imageName+'" id="'+element.imageName+'" class="corners" /></a></li>');
                });
            });
        });

This is the function that should match the image name from the loop and return the title.
function GetTitle(a,z){
    $.getJSON('BKND/Galleries/'+z+'/titles.json', (adata) => {
        // Handle the JSON data here  
        let zTitle         
    $.grep(adata, function(value) {
        if(value.Img = a){
            zTitle = value.title;
        }
        else{zTitle = " ";}
    });
    console.log(zTitle)
    return zTitle
});
}

No matter how i try, i cant get it right. i almost solved when i put the code inside function in the loop, but then it iterated through it and created doubles of images in the gallery instead.

This question is similar to: How to return a value from a function that calls $.getJSON?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ok. so this is how far i have gotten, so far.
function GetTitle(galleryFolder){

    // Handle the JSON data here  
       var cArray = []
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': true,
            'url': 'BKND/Galleries/'+galleryFolder+'/titles.json',
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                cArray = data
            }
        });

        return cArray;}



//Ladda in galleriet om man väljer i listrutan.
    $(document).on('click','#zmenu>div.item', function(){ //When you click on dropdown with ID #zmenu
        $('#dc_preload_image').empty(); //initialize preloader
        let zGallery=$(this).attr('data-value'); //Get attr data-value from zmenu, to determine which folder you want to access
        let titlesArray = GetTitle(zGallery); //load JSON array into a variable
        var Img //initilase Img?
        var ttls=Object.fromEntries(titlesArray.map(e=>[e.Img,e.title])); //convert JSON array to an object
        $.getJSON('JSON/Gallerys/'+zGallery+'.json', { get_param: 'value' }, (data)=>{  //Get the JSON with all the imagenames from backend
            $.each(data, function(index, element) { //loop through each imgagename and build the htmls structure inside the gallery div
                var Titles =`Title: ${element.imageName} is ${ttls[Img]?`"${ttls[Img]}"`:'unfortunately unknown'}.`
                                    
                $('.galpop-info').galpop();
                $("#dc_preload_image").preloader();    
                $('#dc_preload_image').append('<li><a class="galpop-info" data-galpop-group="info"  title="'+Titles+'" href="BKND/Galleries/'+zGallery+'/pict/'+element.imageName+'"><img src="BKND/Galleries/'+zGallery+'/tmb/'+element.imageName+'" alt="'+element.imageName+'" id="'+element.imageName+'" class="corners" /></a></li>');
            });
        });
    });

Now it works more like i intended, i dont bombard the JSON file (probobly speeding up the process, and instead work with it as an object.
all images is processed (ive checked with a console.log), but i think there is something wrong with this line
$.each(data, function(index, element) { //loop through each imgagename and build the htmls structure inside the gallery div
            var Titles =`Title: ${element.imageName} is ${ttls[Img]?`"${ttls[Img]}"`:'unfortunately unknown'}.`

because all images is coming back with the line 'unfortunately unknown'
Is there a better way to do this, please, inform an uninformed :)

(This is a major rewrite of my answer - you can find previous versions of this post here.)
Your original attempt would involve frequent $.getJSON('BKND/Galleries/'+z+'/titles.json) calls (at least one call for each image in your gallery) to get the titles. A better approach would be to get the information once and store it in a dictionary. Below I prepared a little demo, based on publicly available data, mimicking a very basic gallery:


$.when(
 $.getJSON("https://dummyjson.com/users/").then(d=>d.users.map(u=>u.username)),
 $.getJSON("https://dummyjson.com/users/").then(d=>Object.fromEntries(d.users.map(u=>[u.username,u.firstName+" "+u.lastName])))
).then((usrs,ttls)=>
   // Now we can build the gallery:
      $("#container").html(usrs.map(u=>
        `<img src="https://dummyjson.com/icon/${u}/128" title="${ttls[u]}">${ttls[u]}`
      ).join("<br>"))
);
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>



Update, in response to OP's "answer" post:
You can use the async:false option in an Ajax call but that will create a negative user experience. The browser will effectively freeze while it is receiving the data.
Nonetheless, I have taken your code and tweaked it in some places to make it work. The demo uses https://dummyjson.com as a public data source.
(( I would still recommend you to use the $.when(...).then() construct as demonstrated in my snippet above. ))


function GetTitle(galleryFolder){
// Handle the JSON data here  
   var cArray = []
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,  // **** Attention: this will block your page while the data is being retrieved! *****
        'global': true,
    //  'url': 'BKND/Galleries/'+galleryFolder+'/titles.json',
        'url': 'https://dummyjson.com/'+galleryFolder,
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            cArray = data[galleryFolder].map(e=>({Img:e.image, title:e.name || e.firstName+" "+e.lastName })); // mimick the titles array ...
        }
    });
    return cArray;
}

//Ladda in galleriet om man väljer i listrutan.
$(document).on('click','#zmenu>div.item', function(){ //When you click on dropdown with ID #zmenu
    $('#dc_preload_image').empty(); //initialize preloader
    let zGallery=$(this).attr('data-value'); //Get attr data-value from zmenu, to determine which folder you want to access
    let titlesArray = GetTitle(zGallery); //load JSON array into a variable
    ttls=Object.fromEntries(titlesArray.map(e=>[e.Img,e.title])); //convert JSON array to an object
    // console.log(ttls);return;
//  $.getJSON('JSON/Gallerys/'+zGallery+'.json', { get_param: 'value' }, (data)=>{  //Get the JSON with all the imagenames from backend
    $.getJSON('https://dummyjson.com/'+zGallery, { get_param: 'value' }, (data)=>{  //Get the JSON with all the imagenames from backend
        // a little adjustment for my dummy data:
        data=data[zGallery];
        
        $.each(data, function(index, element) { //loop through each imgagename and build the htmls structure inside the gallery div
            element.imageName=element.image; // adjustement for my dummy data ... ;-)
            var title =`Title for ${element.imageName} is: ${ttls[element.imageName]?`${ttls[element.imageName]}`:'unfortunately unknown'}.`;
            $('#dc_preload_image').append('<li><a class="galpop-info" data-galpop-group="info"  title="'+title
            +'" href="BKND/Galleries/'+zGallery+'/pict/'+element.imageName+'"><img src="'+element.imageName+'" alt="'+element.imageName+'" id="'+element.imageName+'" class="corners" /></a></li>');
        });
        // the following expressions only need to be executed once - after the $.each() loop!
        //                           ========================================================
        // $('.galpop-info').galpop();
        // $("#dc_preload_image").preloader();    
    });
});
div.item { padding: 6px; margin:6px; display: inline-block; background-color: #ddd; 
           border: 1px solid #888; cursor:pointer }
li img   {height: 100px}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="zmenu">
<div class="item" data-value="users">users</div>
<div class="item" data-value="recipes">recipes</div>
</div>
<div id="dc_preload_image"></div>



Apart from not using async:false I would also recommend you to replace the frequent .append() calls by a single .html() call. This way the complete html markdown will be parsed and rendered only once by the browser instead of the page being re-rendered for each individual image.
I could not resist and wrote the async version with $.when(...).then(), see below:


function GetTitle(galleryFolder){ // this function returns a "thenable" ...
  //               'BKND/Galleries/'+galleryFolder+'/titles.json'
  return $.getJSON('https://dummyjson.com/'+galleryFolder        )
          .then(data => data[galleryFolder].map(e=>({Img:e.image, title:e.name || e.firstName+" "+e.lastName }))) // mimick the titles array ...   
}

//Ladda in galleriet om man väljer i listrutan.
$(document).on('click','#zmenu>div.item', function(){ // When you click on dropdown with ID #zmenu ...
    let zGallery=$(this).attr('data-value');                 // get gallery name
    $.when( // ***** read both .json files at the same time: *****
      GetTitle(zGallery).then(d=>d.map(e=>[e.Img,e.title])), // get titles and ...
      $.getJSON('https://dummyjson.com/'+zGallery).then(d=>d[zGallery].map(e=>e.image)) // image names. 
    ).then((ttlarr,imgs)=>{ // after the data has arrived in parallel streams, process it:
        const ttls=Object.fromEntries(ttlarr);               // convert array to lookup dictionary
        $("#dc_preload_image").html(imgs.map((img,i)=>       // create whole HTML markdown in one go
          `<li><a class="galpop-info" data-galpop-group="info" 
           title="Title for ${img} is: ${ttls[img]?`${ttls[img]}`:'unfortunately unknown'}"
           href="BKND/Galleries/'+zGallery+'/pict/${img}"><img 
           src="${img}" alt="${img}" id="${img}" class="corners"/></a>${ttls[img]}</li>`
        ).join("\n")); //.preloader() ;
        // $('.galpop-info').galpop();   
    });
});
div.item { padding: 6px; margin:6px; display: inline-block; background-color: #ddd; 
           border: 1px solid #888; cursor:pointer }
li img   {height: 100px}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="zmenu">
<div class="item" data-value="users">users</div>
<div class="item" data-value="recipes">recipes</div>
</div>
<div id="dc_preload_image"></div>




Yes!! this was actually my thoughts to when i was trying to solve it.. why would i go into second JSON over and over again,, didnt seem like a good idea.
So i did, just what you suggested.. i stored the JSON in a variable instead. and are trying to access that variable from when i iterate through the pictures.. BUT!. how do i access the different part in the variable.. i checked it and it is truly a JSON array.. but i just want to compare the image name and then extract the title-

I am really really close..... !!! I had to modify your answer,, but i get all the imagenames as keys. it just says that all are unknown,,,

check out my pasted code here:
https://pastecode.dev/s/n53rrgqd

In getTitle() you are making the classic mistake of returning (and using) the variable cArray before it receives its content in the callback of your $.ajax() call. There was a reason for my using the $.when(...).then() construct!

Only now I noticed you set the  async property: It is never a good idea to use async:false in an $.ajax() call as this will effectively freeze the browser for your users.

The reason why your script in pastecode.dev does not work is that you define and reference the variable Img but you never initialise it. And: please always post all of your code in a code snippet within your question in Stackoveflow!

Thank you @Carsten- Im sorry, i usually dont post much on Stack Overflow, i just use it to read..
I will try to add an answer where more of the code is included. If you could look at it and see where im going wrong.
i have gone from accessing JSON file at every image to load it into a varaible and work with that, so i have come far longer than when i started.

Thank you Carsten, ive got it to work now.. i did some alterations after your notes and changed back async to false, because when i checked the ttls object it was empty.
I am aware that async:false is not good, but honestly, the only thing that happens is that it reads the JSON, and put it in a variable before proceeding to the loop.
i will try to improve the code, but i have to learn more about $.when.() $.then()
thank you again.. it now works exactly as i intended.

Your problem already seems to have an answer on Stackoverflow. You can use a callback (you give a function as a parameter to your function and you call the callback function with the title parameter instead of returning the title). Otherwise you can use a promise but you'll need to use async.
An example of callback:
function GetTitle(a, z, callback) {
  $.getJSON("BKND/Galleries/" + z + "/titles.json", (adata) => {
    // Handle the JSON data here
    let zTitle = " ";
    $.each(adata, function (_, value) {
      if (value.Img == a) {
        zTitle = value.title;
      }
    });

    callback(zTitle);
  });
}


And how to use it:
GetTitle(element.imageName, zGallery, (title) => {
    console.log(title)
})

